# Shrink button font size in Stackview (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have two stackViews with buttons in each one.  At my chosen font size, they  extend off the screen on smaller phones.

I want to reduce the font size of ALL buttons in BOTH stackViews and want all buttons to have the same font size.  Is there a simple way to dynamically adjust the font size of all buttons in both stackViews so that they all fit properly and have the same font size?

I could hard-wire it by counting the characters in each title of the largest stack view then calculate the percentage of the view width and scale the font size for all of them but I am wondering if there is anything built-in.

("fillEqually" won't work because the button titles have different lengths so the buttons are different widths.)

Here is an example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sorry,I don't quite understand what you mean.
In my opinion, the width of button is calculated automatically. By default, we don't need to specify size and font, and swiftui can display normally. If you need to set font size, you can continue to specify font after button.[image]

set font like this:
[image]

Comment: I rewrote the question to try to clarify.  It's a horizontal stackView.  On smaller phones, some of the characters of the last button extend off the screen.  I'd like to reduce the font size for smaller phones, but don't want to do that on larger devices.

Comment: This is really a challenging problem. I tried to limit the performance of frame on small screen by specifying the width and height range of frame

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to display the frame on a small screen device by specifying the minimum and maximum width and height values of the frame, as well as the number of rows, which may be helpful[image]

Comment: The buttons and stackView were created in Storyboard so that simplifies some things.  But I will probably have to resort to hard-wiring it. My first thought is to multiply the font size by `maxCharsInViewWidth/TotalCharsInLongestStackview` and apply that to all labels.  Or maybe `stackViewWidth/ScreenWidth`...